# OpenCV -- record browser window instead of capturing camera output?

Tags: macos, opencv, video-capture, screen-capture

I'm trying to get started with OpenCV by trying to write a simple screen recorder -- one that can perform continuous or polled capture of a GUI window on Mac.  For example, I could capture the client area of a browser window.

I'm sure this is possible, but I don't know where to start -- any pointers?  Is the framegrabber to read the GUI window an OSX/Cocoa thing, or an OpenCV call?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to deal with the operating system you're dealing with. I've seen some software where they install a driver. It emulates a camera and streams your desktop into the camera. That way you can use OpenCV's functions to get access to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to deal with MacOSX components as CoreVideo... and to make some objective-c bindings.